# ng-change not fired from checkbox inside label

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some HTML like this:

```
<input ng-controller="cboxCtrl" type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="hideCompleted" ng-change="hideChanged()"/>
```

and a controller like this:

```
angular.module('simple-todos').controller('cboxCtrl', ['$scope',  
function ($scope) {
    console.log("starting");

    $scope.hideChanged = function () {
        console.log("in hideChanged() ");
    };
}]); // end controller
```

It works fine and I see the message on the console when I click the checkbox. However, if I add a label around the checkbox:

```
<label>
    <input ng-controller="cboxCtrl" type="checkbox" 
           ng-model="hideCompleted" ng-change="hideChanged()"/>
    Some text to explain the checkbox
</label>
```

The ng-change function does not run when I click the checkbox. I expect it has something to do with scoping but I cannot figure out what. If I replace labels with divs (which of course does not give a "nice" laýout), the ng-change function is again executed as expected.

Comment: how about moving `ng-controller="cboxCtrl" type="checkbox" 
           ng-model="hideCompleted" ng-change="hideChanged()"` on the label element?

Comment: Good question, welcome to SO!

Comment: Works in my chrome as expected http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/JGbNgJ?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a jsfiddle with your code and it works for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/jfplataroti/hphb8c4v/5/

```js
angular.module('simple-todos', []).controller('cboxCtrl', ['$scope', cboxCtrl]);


function cboxCtrl($scope) {
  console.log("starting");

  $scope.hideChanged = function() {
    console.log("in hideChanged() ");
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="simple-todos">
  <label>
    <input ng-controller="cboxCtrl" type="checkbox" ng-model="hideCompleted" ng-change="hideChanged()" />some text for the label
  </label>
</div>
```

would you mind sharing your complete code?

Comment: Hi. I just realized it must have somthing to do with it running as a Meteor application. Because I have also now tried without anything else and here it works fine. Thank you for tipping me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

clicking on label also triggers ng-change,  you can click the label of a checkbox/radio to check/uncheck It should trigger the scoped function.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the browser you are trying to run this code. Also do check it on other browsers you have installed. AngularJS no longer supports IE8 or earlier. 
link here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your ng-change on the checkbox to the surrounding label's ng-click

```
<label ng-click="hideChanged()">
    <input ng-controller="cboxCtrl" type="checkbox" ng-model="hideCompleted" />
    Some text to explain the checkbox
</label>
```